# How to set Netgear FVS338 as "Interior Router"?

Tags: router, subnet

I have a NETGEAR FVS338 ProSafe VPN Firewall Router. I planned to use it as Interior Router that seating in back of my Sagemcom Gateway F@st 5366 TN-A.

I'm running quite few business application servers in my home office. The Sagemcom networks configured as:

```
Local IPv4 Address  10.0.1.1
Local Subnet Mask   255.255.0.0
Local Ethernet Mac address  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Public IPv4 Address 58.105.xxx.xxx
Public Subnet Mask  255.255.240.0
Default Gateway 58.105.160.2
Primary DNS Server  198.142.152.164
Secondary DNS Server    198.142.152.165
```

When FVS338 plugged into sagemcom network, configured it as:

[image: configuration]

From above image you can see, I had created a different network (10.0.2.0/24) for Netgear FVS338 LAN under Sagemcom network (10.0.1.0/24). Wan side (Broadband configure) have IP address 10.0.1.92 seating sagemcom networks as Netgear gateway IP.

I tried add router to my MacOS Host in Sagemcom network to access subnet 10.0.2.0/24. by run [sudo route -n add -net 10.0.2.0/24 10.0.1.92]

Then, I set up NetGear FVS338 [Security] -> [Firewall] -> [Attack Checks] -> [WAN Security Checks] by tick [Respond to Ping on Internet Ports].

Then, I ping 10.0.1.92 and 10.0.2.1 success

Then, When I tried to configure [LAN WAN Rules] by add an [Inbound Services] to expose host 10.0.2.203 that seat in NetGear FVS3338 network.

[image: status]

I tried to ping the exposed host under Netgear FVS338, but I never get it through.

I login to Netgear FVS338 from command line by USING CLI, and ping 10.0.2.203 from Netgear FVS338 self, the ping works fine, but I ping 10.0.2.203 from WAN side (Sagemcom network), I never get it through.

I am very confused. Any idea?

Comment: You probably want to turn off NAT, and set a route from your sagecom to your netgear.

Comment: @vidario. Sagemcom don't support add static route in configuration setting. NAT services were enabled in both Sagemcom Route and NetGear FVS338 Currently, Which one I should turn off to try? Please advise!

Comment: No problem :) Best of luck with getting a good solution and happy new year :)